# Plot data in R from Raspberry Pi temp sensor

Tags: r, datetime, raspberry-pi, datetime-format

Helping students with analyzing their data after they launch a weather balloon with a Raspberry Pi temp sensor. Trying to write some code for them in R to allow them to plot the downloaded data. A csv will be written & saved. I have put together some code and can't figure out how to convert the date time to the correct format. This is what I have so far (image of R console is attached)...

```
library(lubridate) # loads package to convert data in csv to dateTime format

myData <- read.csv(file="test_temp.csv") # load csv file and call it myData    
head (myData$dateTime) # view the date time data (as Levels)    
new.dateTime <- as.POSIXct(myData$dateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") # convert to datetime data    
head (new.dateTime) # view the new format - not working!    
plot(Temp ~ new.dateTime, data) # also not working
```

[image: R console with errors]

Comment: You are using `plot(Temp ~ new.dateTime, data)` but I think you mean `plot(Temp ~ new.dateTime, myData)`

Comment: Also your `dateTime` column is being read in as a factor. Use `new.dateTime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(myData$dateTime), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")` or `myData <- read.csv(file="test_temp.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: Please include errors and code samples as text, not images!